# Okhttp based query response error

Tags: android, okhttp

i am using Okhttp to fetch API call
created the logging object then created client object by adding the logging object put url query with request parameters
here is the code

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();

    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(mApiUrl).newBuilder();

    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("q",query);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("api-key",APiUtil.API_key);

    String mUrl = urlBuilder.toString();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(mUrl).build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    callback.onArticleListNotFound();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            //json

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            try{
                String resultResponse = response.body().string();
                List<DocsItem> docsItemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is the funny thing on android monitor
it displays both response code 200
yet it shows error when trying to create JsonObject out of the response
*** I AM USING `.string()` NOT `.toString()` method

in case if you thought that was the bug
thank you for your time guyz

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200  http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=art&api-key=ca010b80f32146a79344494a0052e9eb (15562ms, unknown-length body)
W/MALI: glDrawArrays:770: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 6000
D/OkHttp: Callback failure for call to http://api.nytimes.com/...
D/OkHttp: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
D/OkHttp:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:634)
D/OkHttp:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:596)
D/OkHttp:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:492)
D/OkHttp:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:42)
```

Comment: Watch out what you share. You should not share api keys with others

Comment: What emulator do you use?

Comment: i'm using a device, HTC mobile

Comment: any idea on how to tweak the request object?

Comment: found the solution, "https" brings the right response instead of the official http in the Api documentation, although i'm struggling with gson index out of bound exception for now.